# NetTopologySuite polygon algorithm crossing International Date Line

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

I am using the [NetTopolgySuite](http://code.google.com/p/nettopologysuite/) ported to C#, and need to determine if certain Coordinate Latitude/Longitude fall within a specified area defined as an array of Coordinate Latitude/Longitude values.

So I am trying to use the [CGAlgorithms.IsPointInRing](http://nts.sourceforge.net/docs/v1.2/GisSharpBlog.NetTopologySuite.Algorithm.CGAlgorithms.IsPointInRing.html) method, which for the most works perfectly. The problem arises when I have an area that stradles the International Date Line, e.g. the 1st line from 170 East going East to end at 170 West. When I call the IsPointInRing it returns FALSE even if the Coordinate under test is within the area.

The documentation for IsPointInRing says

> The ring may be oriented in either direction.

which I assume to be clockwise or anticlockwise. I can only assume the ring is being incorrectly determined as the 1st line going from 170 East going WEST to 170 West & not crossing the IDL. My line should be the minor arc, not the major arc.

Can anyone advise how I can test Coordinate inclusion in a Coordinate array that may or may not cross the International Date Line, or if I am using the function incorrectly. I'd prefer to continue using NetTopologySuite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing, I can confirm the NetTopologySuite IsPointInRing procedure is considered to run as the "MAJOR" arc if the "MINOR" arc crosses the 180W/180E meridian. As a workaround, when testing the point against the ring, I am simply shifting all Longitude values from the range 180W..0W to run 180E..360E before calling the function, i.e. 170W = 190E shifted, 170E = 170E unshifted. While not technically correct, it allows me to call the IsPointInRing procedure & get a correct answer.